# d3.js pie chart not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.v4 to draw a pie chart with the following data set:

```
var InternetUsage = [{usage:"no time at all", number:3}, 
                 {usage:"less than an hour a day", number:139}, 
                 {usage:"few hours a day", number:740},
                 {usage:"most of the day", number:122}];
```

I want the color of each slice to be in an range. But running my code nothing except the text label is showing. From my assumption, the problem happens when I want to extract value of a property from the data set. Like `var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { return d.number ;});`may not work as the way I expected. However, I have no idea how to fix it in this case.

The complete code I wrote in .js file is

```
var width = 950
var height = 500;
var radius = 250;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.number ;});


var InternetUsage = [{usage:"no time at all", number:3}, 
                     {usage:"less than an hour a day", number:139}, 
                     {usage:"few hours a day", number:740},
                     {usage:"most of the day", number:122}];

var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(InternetUsage))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

arc.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(InternetUsage[i].usage); });

arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .style("font-size","10px")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d,i) {return InternetUsage[i].usage; });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `d` attribute for you `path` elements:

```
arc.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("d", path) // <== !!!
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(InternetUsage[i].usage); });
```

Pay attention I renamed your path generator function to `path` (you called it as `arc`), because of you use the same variable name for a DOM node (`var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")...`).

```
var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);
```

Working demo:

```js
var width = 950
var height = 500;
var radius = 250;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.number ;});


var InternetUsage = [{usage:"no time at all", number:3}, 
                     {usage:"less than an hour a day", number:139}, 
                     {usage:"few hours a day", number:740},
                     {usage:"most of the day", number:122}];

var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(InternetUsage))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

arc.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(InternetUsage[i].usage); });

arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .style("font-size","10px")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d,i) {return InternetUsage[i].usage; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.2/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a dumb mistake. I am new to d3 and js so I am sometimes confused by those attributes. I thought the problem was caused by  `.value(function(d) { return d.number ;})` because when I add `console.log(InternetUsage.number)`, the result is undefined.

Comment: Not at all. `InternetUsage` it is an array of objects so if you want for instance to get the value that stored in the `number` property of the first object in this array you should do it this way: `console.log(InternetUsage[0].number)`.